# Reg ex to accept digits hyphen and parenthesis (in right order)

Tags: c#, regex

I need a reg ex which accepts 10 to 11 digits phone number, hyphen , parenthesis (in right order) and spaces are allowed (I will remove all of the afterwards).
So all following string should be accepted by it.

```
12223334444
2223334444
1(222)333-4444
1(222) 333-4444
1 (222) 333-4444
1 (222) 333 - 4444
(222)333-4444
(222) 333-4444
(222) 333 - 4444
1-222-333-4444
1 - 222 - 333 - 4444
222-333-4444
222 - 333 - 4444
```

I have made this , but it accepts many other strings

```
^(.*?[.-|\( |]|[0-9][^\d]*(\d+)[^\d].* [.-|\)].*)$
```

I am using C#.

Comment: I don't see much logic behind the regex given here.  Nor do I see any effort on your part to solve it.

Comment: You should look have looked at https://regex101.com/ and reviewed regex videos on Youtube. You've not even disclosed the language you are working on - there are some subtle nuances that are not in all variants.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We're not here to write for you - but to offer guidance..

Comment: `^(?=\D*(?:\d\D*){10,11}$)\d*(?:\s*(?:-\s*|\(\d+\)))?\s*\d+(?:\s*-?\s*\d+)*$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?:1[\s-]*)?(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[\s-]*\d{3}[\s-]*\d{4}$
```

See it [here](https://regex101.com/r/kga0ZT/2/)

Breakdown:

- `^` start of string
- `1[\s-]*` <sub>*(optional)*</sub> Matches a literal `1` and zero or more whitespace characters and/or dashes
- `(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})` matches one of the following:

  - 3 digits `\d{3}` surrounded by opening `\(` and closing `\)` parenthesis
  - 3 digits `\d{3}` not surrounded by parenthesis
- `[\s-]*` zero or more whitespace characters and/or dashes
- `\d{3}` another 3 digits
- `[\s-]*` zero or more whitespace characters and/or dashes
- `\d{4}` another 4 digits
- `$` end of string

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the breakdown, helps a lot.

Comment: Happy to assist